# How to hide infoWindow while using measure tool and showing it back after using it ArcGis JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, events, measurements

I have an infoWinfow set on the click event of the map. I want to disable this event when I'm using the measurement tool and then enable it back after the measurement tool is used. So far I've done this code, where the click event for the infoWindow is disable when the measurement tool is used. I want to enable the click event back after the measurement tool is used. Any ideas on how this could be done? Thanks.

```
function initToolbar(mymap) {
var measurement = new esri.dijit.Measurement({
    map: mymap
}, dojo.byId('measurementDiv'));
measurement.startup();
measurement.setTool("area", false);

measurement.areaToggleButton = function () {
    this.clearResult();
    this.setTool("area");
    dojo.disconnect(clickHandler);
};
measurement.distanceToggleButton= function () {
    this.clearResult();
    this.setTool("distance");
    dojo.disconnect(clickHandler);
};
}
```